# Cardinality of preimages of finite mappings

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory, integer-partitions

Let $1\leq n,r$ be integers and $f:[1,n]\rightarrow[1,r]$ a mapping. For $1\leq j\leq r$, let $\epsilon_j:=|f^{-1}(j)|$. I want to show that
$$|f^{-1}(\epsilon_j)|=\epsilon_j$$
for all $1\leq j\leq r$. It seems like it might hold but I'm having difficulty proving/disproving it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Any non surjective function has a $j$ such that $\epsilon _j=0,$ the inverse is not even defined there. Another example would be just $f=1\mapsto 2, 2\mapsto 2,3\mapsto 3$

$$|f^{-1}(3)|=1,|f^{-1}(1)|=0.$$
It seems really strong your condition. Why you think is true?